# Delete rows between certain values

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like make a task for my work way more simple, but in pretty lost since I'm just starting to learn VBA.

What I wanna make easier is a process of removing certaing data from an excel sheet.

Please, see the image, I think it's easier to understand.

[image]

I'd like to ask for an input of a market in column P. Let's say the user enters "Portugal". Then it would look for the rows that have that value in column P and delete the ones that doesn't contain information for Portugal (e.g. it would delete rows from 6 to 9 and 21 to 25, but rows 2-5 and 10-20 should not be deleted).

Any good ideas? I think it should be simple somehow but I can't think of any solution.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Looks like you 1st want to focus on filling down the values in column P so you can start utilizing the filter.

Comment: Why not just filter it? Anyway once you've filtered it, you can copy the visible cells of the range using `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy` . Or if you want you can create an "opposite" filter (in your case all those that are not "Portugal") and then delete the visible cells with `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete` .

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) . Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: this is a fairly easy sub to write.  here a suggestion in order to open the coding suggestions: write 2 subs. In Sub 1 ask the user the country of interest using inputBox, pass this value to sub 2. in sub iterate through through column 16 to figure out where the country rows are. that should be enough code to show that you are on the right direction then we will be able to help you with the details.

Answer (score 4):

Let me teach you some Excel magic:

- Select the entire column "P".
- Press <kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd> , choose "Special" and then "Blanks".
- Click in the address bar and type `=P2`.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl+ENTER</kbd> (don't forget the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button!)

This should fill in the "P" column as you desire and from then on, you can use the basic autofilter.

Comment: I did not know this trick with keyboard. Awesome. Upvoted